# TableView code to display plist is not working, Is it because it has to be on a UITableView Controller? (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, plist, tableview

I cannot get my plist to display on my app. I need to use TableView and not a TableView Controller. Im not sure if I have followed the wrong code when first attempting it. Please take a look. 
m. file is:

```
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "NewsFeedViewController.h"
#import "BuySharesViewController.h"
#import "SellSharesViewController.h"
#import "FinancesViewController.h"
#import "CurrentHoldingsViewController.h"
#import "TradingHistoryViewController.h"
#import "LeaderboardViewController.h"
#import "HowToPlayViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "InitViewController.h"

@interface SellSharesViewController ()

{
    BOOL isSearching;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *CurrentDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *shares;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *shareValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *number;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *shareName;

- (void)resetSearch;
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm;

@end


@implementation SellSharesViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    isSearching = NO;
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shares" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.allNames = dict;
    //NSArray *array = [[self.names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    //self.keys = (NSMutableArray *)array;

    [self resetSearch];
    [self.table reloadData];
    [self.table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0) animated:NO];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return ([self.keys count] > 0) ? [self.keys count] : 1 ;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if ([self.keys count] == 0)
        return 0 ;

    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [self.names objectForKey:key];
    return nameSection.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [self.names objectForKey:key];

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  {

    if ([self.keys count] == 0)
        return nil;


    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:section];
    if (key == UITableViewIndexSearch)
        return nil;

    return key;
}



/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (isSearching)
        return nil;

    return self.keys;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Custom Methods

- (void) resetSearch {
    NSMutableDictionary *allNamesCopy = [self.allNames mutableDeepCopy];
    self.names = allNamesCopy;

    NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [keyArray addObjectsFromArray:[[self.allNames allKeys]
                                   sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
    [keyArray insertObject:UITableViewIndexSearch atIndex:0];
    self.keys = keyArray;
}

- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {
    NSMutableArray *sectionsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self resetSearch];

    for (NSString *key in self.keys) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [self.names valueForKey:key];
        NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSString *name in array ) {
            if ([name rangeOfString:searchTerm
                            options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
                [toRemove addObject:name];
        }

        if ([array count] == [toRemove count])
            [sectionsToRemove addObject:key];

        [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
    }
    [self.keys removeObjectsInArray:sectionsToRemove];
    [self.table reloadData];
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.search resignFirstResponder];
    isSearching = NO;
    self.search.text = @"";
    [self.table reloadData];
    return indexPath;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Search Bar Delegate Methods
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *searchTerm = [searchBar text];
    [self handleSearchForTerm:searchTerm];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    textDidChange:(NSString *)searchTerm {
    if ([searchTerm length] == 0) {
        [self resetSearch];
        [self.table reloadData];
        return;
    }
    [self handleSearchForTerm:searchTerm];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = NO;
    self.search.text = @"" ;
    [self resetSearch];
    [self.table reloadData];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
    [self.table reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)titleForHeaderInSection
               atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:index];
    if (key == UITableViewIndexSearch) {
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        return NSNotFound;
    }
    else {
        return index;
    }
}




@end
```

h.file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SellSharesViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *sellShares;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rowSelectedDisplay;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *removeShare;



@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *menuBtn;

-(IBAction)removeShareButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

Feel free to ask for anything else that may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the uitableview property to strong instead of weak. I do this to have a strong pointer to the tableview so it does not get deallicateded.  Also you need to connect the delegate and datasource of the uitableview to the uiviewcontroller in the storyboard. So the protocol methods will be called in your uiviewcontroller. If they are not connected the protocol methods are not being called so nothing will show up in your table view.

If you have an array of dictionaries the fornumberofrows return [myarray count];

Connecting the datasource and delegate in the storyboard is overlooked a lot of times so check this first. I hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, It worked. I did not connect the delegate and datasource to the controller. Thanks so much. Next step is adding 'share' selected  to another plist on a different controller to keep history. Any ideas please advice!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set Delegate and Datasource in the XIB? 
[image]

Other things you need to check is , 
Put break point in below methods and check if it s firing

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Make sure you are not returning zero in the first two methods.

If either of first 2 methods are not firing then it means you did not added the datasource in XIB